# Iterating through an arbitrarily nested array in python and changing matching values

Tags: python, arrays, string, recursion, traversal

I have an arbitrarily nested array of values that looks like this:

```
['"multiply"', 'ALAssn ', ['ACmp ', ['Ge ', ['Var "n"'], ' ', ['Num 0']]], ['ALAssn ', ['ACmp ', ['Eq ', ['Var "p"'], ' ', ['Mul ', ['Var "n"'], ' ', ['Var "m"']]]]]
```

and I need to try and figure out a way to parse through the every value in the array and format it so that:

1. Each array of length 1 is split into two separate values:

-- **Example:** `['Var "n"']` should now become `["Var", "n"]` and `['Num 0']` now becomes `["Num", 0]`.

2. All instances of empty list values are removed.

-- **Example:** `['Ge ', ['Var "n"'], ' ', ['Num 0']]` now becomes `['Ge ', ['Var "n"'], ['Num 0']]`

3. The whitespace in any string is removed.

-- **Example:** `'Ge '` now becomes `'Ge'`

The given snippet is a portion of a much larger string that needs to parsed. I understand what needs to be done at a high level..ie:

1. Once I get to an list of length 1, `list.split(" ")` to split into two separate elements, then trim `arr[1]` to get rid of the extra quotation marks
2. If `el` is an empty string for every element in the list, `list.remove(el)`
3. Check `if isinstance(el, string)` of every element when traversing, and if true, `el.replace(" ", "")` to rid of the whitespace.

My only issue comes when traversing through every single element in the list. I've tried doing so recursively and iteratively, but so far haven't been able to crack it.

Ideally, I traverse through every single element, and then once I hit an element that meets the criteria, set that element equal to the change that I want to make on it. This is only really the case for points 1 and 3.

**EDIT:**

Thank you so much for the answers given. I have one more addition I would like to make.

Assume too I have a nested identifiers like `'Reads "a"'` as the first value of an array, with the possibility of having addition identifiers like `Write "a"` in the same level. These also needs to be converted to the format `["Read", "a"]`. See the change in the large list below. How would I go about doing this?

```
['Read "a"', ['Add', ['Var', 'i'], ['Num', '1']]], 'Write "a"', ['Add', ['Var', 'i'], ['Num', '1']], ['Var', 't']]
```

The point of these values `'Read'` and `'Write'` is so that, when traversing the list, we know the "type" of the next n elements of the list corresponding to that identifier. We can distinguish them basically by saying they are are the only values in the nested list that will not be lists themselves.

For example: `['identifier', [], [], []]`

Assume it is known that the `identifier` type contains 3 lists, `first`, `second`, `third`. The goal is to read identifier and then store `first`, `second`, and `third` as nodes in a tree, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems like it would be easiest to deal with by constructing a new list with the fixed-up items, rather than trying to modify the existing list in place. This would let you use recursion to deal with the nesting, while using iteration over the flat parts of each list.

I'd structure the code like this:

```
def process(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:                     # special case for one-element lists
        result = lst[0].split()
        result[1] = result[1].strip('"')  # strip quotation marks
        return result

    result = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result.append(process(item))  # recurse on nested lists
        else: # item is a string
            stripped = item.strip()       # remove leading and trailing whitespace
            if stripped:
                result.append(stripped)   # keep only non-empty strings
    return result
```

Comment: This solution is easy to follow, but can it be adjusted to fit the edit?

Comment: The edit's special case seems underspecified. What makes `'read "a"'` distinctive? The space? The quotation marks? Are `'read'` and `'write'` hard coded special cases? Detail that out and the way to implement it should be straightforward. At worse, you might need a simple regex test.

Comment: `'Read '` and `Write` are the only values in the nested list that will not be lists themselves.

For example: ['identifier', [], [], []]

The point of the identifier is so that, when traversing the list, we know the "type" of the next n elements of the list corresponding to that identifier. I've also added this to the question to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can collapse 1 and 3 into one operation:

```py
def sanitize(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        if len(item) == 1:
            item = item[0].split()
        return [output for i in item if (output := sanitize(i))]
    return item.strip('" ')  # Strips both '"' and ' '.


item = ['"multiply"', 'ALAssn ', ['ACmp ', ['Ge ', ['Var "n"'], ' ', ['Num 0']]], ['ALAssn ', ['ACmp ', ['Eq ', ['Var "p"'], ' ', ['Mul ', ['Var "n"'], ' ', ['Var "m"']]]]]]
sanitize(item)
# Returns: ['multiply', 'ALAssn', ['ACmp', ['Ge', ['Var', 'n'], ['Num', '0']]], ['ALAssn', ['ACmp', ['Eq', ['Var', 'p'], ['Mul', ['Var', 'n'], ['Var', 'm']]]]]]
```

Comment: This is a clean solution, but do you have any ideas how I can modify it to handle the edit I made?

Comment: The last line, item.strip('" '), is the catch-all for string values. Transform that string into whatever you need.